# Media Items all return 404

Tags: configuration, media-library

On sitecore 8.2 inital version.

I am doing the following:

```cs
var myImageItem = (MediaItem) Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["MyImageField"].Item;
if (myImageItem != null)
{
    viewModel.ImageAlt = myImageItem.Alt;
    var url = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(myImageItem);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
    {
        viewModel.ImageUrl = url;
    }
}
```

The url however is always returning a `404 item not found`. The logs show the following:

```
14008 13:40:38 WARN  Request is redirected to document not found page. Requested url: /media/94EF96BAA8214F6D9262C9FCB2137F2C.ashx, User: sitecore\admin, Website: MyWebsite

15432 13:40:58 WARN  Request is redirected to document not found page. Requested url: /media/94EF96BAA8214F6D9262C9FCB2137F2C.ashx, User: sitecore\admin, Website: MyWebsite
```

I have turned off mediarequest extension default of `.ashx` by following instructions on: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-idiosyncrasies-media-urls

Even with this turned off .ashx media urls still being returned.

Comment: Have you checked if your media items are published in the web database?

Comment: @SzymonKuzniak yes I have. I triple checked and they are.

Comment: In reference to the above: can you see the media items when you're previewing on the CM?

Also: if you manually change the URL to what you think it should be - do you get a result?

I'm not sure if it's possible to have a media URL without a -/ (or ~/) at the start?

Comment: Sorry for obviuos question but better check :) From another direction: is /-/media/94EF96BAA8214F6D9262C9FCB2137F2C.ashx url return 404 or not?

Comment: @OwenNiblock I can see on CM and can see them on the web database for the CDs

Comment: @SzymonKuzniak yes 404s

Comment: @OwenNiblock the urls have /-/media/94EF96BAA8214F6D9262C9FCB2137F2C.ashx and they still 404. /-/ is the default, however when this is requested nothing is logged.

Comment: One more thing what about tildas? /~/media/94EF96BAA8214F6D9262C9FCB2137F2C.ashx Do you have any item called media?

Comment: ~ tildas also return 404 and no item named media. @SzymonKuzniak

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem lays in casting to `MediaItem` object, you should use `ImageField` instead.

Use this:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField myImageItem = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["MyImageField"];
```

then:

```cs
Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(myImageItem.MediaItem);
```

Comment: sorry a typo not typing but casting

Comment: ahh good spot!! Let me give this a try.

Comment: This worked yay!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the error message your media item URLs are being generated as `/media`. The default settings in Sitecore 8.2 are to generate with `/-/media`. Browse to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and check the value of `Media.MediaLinkPrefix`. By default it should be empty.

If the media prefix has intentionally been changed the you also need to update the following settings to add your new prefix as the trigger:

```
<sitecore>    
  <settings>
    <setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" set:value="media" />
  </settings>

  <!-- Media handler prefixes -->
  <customHandlers>
    <handler patch:before="*[@trigger='-/media/']" trigger="media/" handler="sitecore_media.ashx" />
  </customHandlers>

  <mediaLibrary>
    <mediaPrefixes>
      <prefix value="-/media"/>
    </mediaPrefixes>
  </mediaLibrary>
</sitecore>
```

Note that the trigger prefix should be unique. This is why Sitecore uses the `-/` part of the default prefix. If you have content which matches the prefix trigger then it will match as a media item instead, e.g. `/products/media/item/` try to match as a media item. Either ensure the trigger is unique or disallow users creating items with that name.

Comment: <setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value=""/> it is empty in showconfix.aspx :'(

Comment: ahh good shout, making sure those are there!

Comment: Noticed a dirty ~/media defined under mediaprefixes node. However this didn't resolve issue :O. I changed to the default -/media